# SQL INNER JOIN issue when value as 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have shortened my query & posted only relevant parts. There are many `INNER JOINS`. Here is the query :-

```
DECLARE 
    @startdate DATE = '2018-05-01',
    @enddate   DATE = '2018-05-05';
    WITH calendar
            AS (SELECT @startdate AS Dates
                UNION ALL
                SELECT Dateadd(dd, 1, Dates)
                FROM   calendar
                WHERE  Dates < @enddate)
    SELECT emp.Code, cv1.CategoryName AS Category FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM   calendar c
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Id
                        FROM   [dbo].[Employee] where CompanyId = 1) E
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM   [dbo].[ShiftSchedule] t
            WHERE  c.Dates = t.ShiftDate
            AND E.Id = t.EmployeeId AND CompanyId = 11)) AS c 
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Employee] emp
            ON c.Id = emp.Id                
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Category] cv1 
            ON cv1.id = emp.Category   
            AND emp.Id IN ( 400 )
    OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

The problem here is in the `INNER JOIN` of `[dbo].[Category]`.

In very rare cases - Category is found `0` in `Employee` Table. So what I want is if Category is 0 then also that record should be included in Result Set. Currently it skips the Records with 0.

Can this be achieved in the above query?

> Example :- In Employee table I have an employee Steve & in Category
>   Column Value is 0.  And in Category Table in column Id, there is no
>   record with 0. So this Employee Steve is not coming in result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're simply asking for your employee to be returned even when it cannot be matched to a category. That's easy: that's what a `LEFT JOIN` is for. There's no reason to treat `0` as special here: based on your description, it seems to me as if you'd want the same for any other values that don't exist as category IDs, it's just that there are no such other values.

Comment: I tried with LEFT JOIN, it was working correctly till i added an extra condition `AND emp.Id IN ( 400 )` (check edited question). It gives me Results for All employees not Just with ID 400.

Comment: @Anup Of course that wouldn't work. That should be part of the filter (after `WHERE`), not part of the join condition. For inner joins, filters and join conditions have the same effect, but I'd still encourage you to think carefully about what belongs where.